# Why is BatchNormalization causing severe overfitting to my data?

Tags: deep-learning, overfitting, regularization, batch-normalization

So I've been making a mini version of VGGNet, trying to tweak the hyperparameters to match the CIFAR-100 dataset.

It was running slow at first but I was able to get decent accuracy after 60 epochs or so.
However, when I added BatchNormalization layers to my two fully-connected hidden layers, it started learning at like 20% accuracy immediately, but began overfitting my data so badly that after 7 epochs my validation didn't improve from 0.01, compared to 20+ testing accuracy.

Why would adding these layers which are supposed to act as a regularizer, actually cause severe overfitting instead? I'm confused.

Comment: How big are the batches? I had a similar symptom when I accidentally applied BN to batches of size 1. BN relies on the batches being big enough that the batch average matches the training/test/validation set average.

Comment: Oh like 256. I just read the ResNet paper. Do you think it's the degradation problem that He et Al addressed on their paper?